# Mod_rewrite doesn't seem to work for this rewrite rule

Tags: mod-rewrite, apache2

I'm trying to set up a simple rewrite rule so that something like

```
mysite.com/admin
```

becomes

```
mysite.com/new/admin
```

I have tried the following :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^admin.*  new/admin [L]
```

But that doesn't seem to be working. It just results in a 404 error, which is the same as what I was getting before. My logs don't seem to show anything. Here is my configuration file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
  ServerName mysite.com
  DocumentRoot /var/www

  <Directory />

   Options FollowSymLinks
   AllowOverride None
  </Directory>
  <Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
  </Directory>
```

If anyone knows the proper rewrite rule to settle this, that would be most excellent!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^admin(.*) new/admin$1 [L,R,QSA]
```

Flags explanation:

- `L` - last rule (processing will stop at that point)
- `R` - redirect (without this flag, apache will do *sub-request* and will still show the original URL to the browser)
- `QSA` - append the original query-string

Comment: It sort of works... if I place it under my /var/www directory block it redirects to mysite/var/www/new/admin, if I place it outside of both directory blocks it creates mysite.com//admin/ (note the double /), and it doesn't do anything inside the other block

Comment: you need to place it inside `Directory` block that corresponds to your `DocumentRoot`. Oh, and add `RewriteBase /`

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try the following with the slash..

RewriteRule ^admin.*  /new/admin [L]

Comment: Can you set your loglevel to debug for apache, access URL and see what is printed in error.log?